# What is the name of the design pattern used by this validation code?

Tags: python, exception, design-patterns, terminology

I have found it convenient to implement validation directly in the risen exception classes like:

```
>>> class IsNoneError(ValueError):
...     @classmethod
...     def validate(cls, value):
...         if value is None:
...             raise cls
... 
>>> IsNoneError.validate(1)
>>> IsNoneError.validate(None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in validate
__main__.IsNoneError
```

The pattern I am asking about is **embedding of the validation routine in the exception class which is being raised if the validation fails**. As I try to use single responsibility principle in my code, I need to have a separate exception for every failure, which then may be translated to a message in arbitrary natural language by a separate module.
Following the pattern allows me to have all my validation code in one place.

As there is nothing new under the sun I guess someone had already invented this exception-validator class pattern. What is its name then, which I may use talking to other pythonists to be understood?

Also, what are possible drawbacks of this design pattern?

Answer (score 0):

That most probably fits in with [design by contract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract) since your code acts as a [guard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guard_(computer_science)).

It is not so much a design pattern but could rather be categorized as [defensive programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defensive_programming).

I have something [similar](https://github.com/Shuttle/Shuttle.Core.Contract) that I use in the .Net space.

There really shouldn't be any drawbacks since your are ensuring that your code is going to perform as expected.

Comment: Indeed, I use similar (more complicated) code for defensive programming, but the design pattern I am asking about is implementation of the validation by the exception class itself. Pleas see the edited question.